# What is the resulting solution after leaching hardwood ash with water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution

After doing online research, I've noticed there are differing interpretations on what happens when ash is mixed with water, so I've come here seeking clarification on what indeed happens, and also clarification for why, since I don't know how to refute what I believe might be the misconceptions.

I understand a component of wood ash is potash (hardwood ash consisting greater portions of it than others). It seems wood-derived potash is primarily potassium carbonate ($\ce{K2CO3}$). I will assume this is the case for the rest of the question, but I'd also like to know what other potassium-containing compounds may be therein.

Another component of wood ash seems to be lime. Most of it seems to be calcium carbonate, but I also hear there is calcium oxide ($\ce{CaO}$). This is where things get tipsy-turvy for me. Taking into account what I've told so far, I don't know for sure what the solution is when ash is mixed with water.

One version is that potassium hydroxide ($\ce{KOH}$) is produced and remains in this solution. I don't know how to "refute" the following explanations supporting $\ce{KOH}$ formations if it's not the case or negligible:

(1) The $\ce{CaO}$ in the ash reacts with the water to form aqueous calcium hydroxide ($\ce{Ca(OH)2}$). The potash, primarily being $\ce{K2CO3}$, dissolves in the water too. Both of these then react with each other to produce $\ce{KOH}$ that becomes part of the solution per the equation: $\ce{Ca(OH)2 + K2CO3 -> CaCO3 + 2KOH}$.

(2) Due to the natural dissociation of water, there are some hydroxide ions present in solution. The potash still dissolves, and as part of that, potassium ions will also be present in solution. Both of these then react to produce $\ce{KOH}$.

The other version I've seen posted around is that no $\ce{KOH}$ is formed by mixing water and ash. this makes sense, especially when I consider the archaic job of an ash burner. Hardwood ash (being more potash rich) is leached with water. The potash dissolves into a solution. The mother liquor is then boiled to leave behind potash powder. If the potash had reacted to produce $\ce{KOH}$, I don't see how this could be the case especially since I think lye instead of potash powder would be left behind.

In short, is the solution water with primarily aqueous $\ce{K2CO3}$ or water with primarily aqueous $\ce{KOH}$? I'd also like an idea of what other impurities may be here in either case.

Comment: It's not really clear from your question, you are aware that in solution, there are only the ions? $\ce{K2CO3 + CaO + H2O -> 2K+ + Ca^{2+} + CO3^{2+} + 2 OH- }$, all in aqueous form.

Comment: I know there are ions. Sorry, I'm trying to say that I've heard some people say the solution is lye water, and others say there is no lye water and it's a myth. An explanation I've seen for lye water is that in the solution, the aqueous potassium ions interact with aqueous hydroxide ions to render the solution lye water (and that if the water is boiled out, potassium hydroxide solute will be left behind). Alternatively, when they say it's not lye water, and the water is boiled out, potash, being potassium carbonate mostly, is left behind.

Comment: Also, regarding your chemical equation, from what I understand, there would be no calcium ions as they should have precipitated out as calcium carbonate

Comment: You're right, calcium carbonate precipitates. That makes the answer to your question pretty obvious. You just need to know how the relative content of calcium and potassium in you wood.